# Nodejs: connect to same socket all time

Tags: node.js, jsp, socket.io

Here the nodeJS code:

```
exports.initialize = function(app,server) {
    var io = require('socket.io');
    var http = require("http");
    var url = require("url");
    io = io.listen(server);
    var userList={}
    io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket){
        socket.on('connectNotfServer', function(message){

                userList[message.userId]=socket;
                console.log("Get connected to user: "+message.userId);

        });
    });

    app.get('/notifyUser', function(req, res){
        var parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url, true);
        var params = parsedUrl.query;

            userList[params.to].emit('serverNotification',{notfication:params.message,id:params.id,time:params.time});
            res.end(JSON.stringify(params));

    });
};
```

Now in `header.jsp`:

```
 var socket = io.connect('myserver:3000');
 socket.on('serverNotification', function (data) {
         console.log("got message");
 });    
 socket.emit('connectNotfServer',{"userId":"123");
```

`header.jsp` is imported in many pages. Now if open page1.jsp then page2.jsp. I got notification but the problem is I got message in page2.jsp not in page1.jsp i.e. I got message always in last opened page.(probably cos of losing old socket connection).

I want that if there is any notifictaion it should be received by all pages. as in FB you will see that if you have new notification it will show red notification indicator in all opened FB page.

I think it will be possible only when same `Socket` instance will be used through out user session.but How?

Comment: temporary solution that i am doing is maintaining a array of socket instance for a userId. if there is any event just iterate through all instance and send message.something like `users[1]=["socket1","socket2"]`